# There’s a lateral movement when the vertical scrollbar is activated

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

code: https://jsfiddle.net/0tgo9ud8/

How do I prevent slight shift sideways when the vertical scrollbar kicks in?

**1st:** Launch the code snippet in full screen mode.

**Next:** Click the exit button that **fades in** to see the shift occur.

How do I keep everything aligned at all times?

Before the scroll bar kicks in?

Before clicking the exit button is the **1st** image.

After is the **2nd** image.

What would need to be adjusted in the code to fix that?

That is all I am trying to do here.

It seems nothing I have tried has worked.

And ideas on what will?

You see the shift occur after the exit button is clicked, right?

How would I keep everything aligned?

So there is no shift.

[image]

Image 2 example:

[image]

```js
/*global YT */
/*jslint browser:true */
/*jslint devel: true */
window.onload = function () {
    const splashScreen = document.querySelector(".splash-screen");
    splashScreen.classList.add("hide");

    const panel = document.querySelector(".panel");
    panel.classList.add("slide");

    const wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
    splashScreen.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
        splashScreen.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        wrap.classList.remove("hide");
    });

    const closeButton = document.querySelector(".exitInitial");
    panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
        closeButton.classList.add("visible");
    });
};


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

    let players = [];

    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100);
        if (player === players[0]) {
            shufflePlaylist(player);
        }
    }

    function shufflePlaylist(player) {
        player.setShuffle(true);
        player.playVideoAt(0);
        player.stopVideo();
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        const eventPlayer = event.target;
        if (eventPlayer !== players[0]) {
            if (event.data === 1) {
                players.forEach(function pauseOtherVideos(player) {
                    const hasIframe = player.getIframe();
                    const isDifferentPlayer = player !== eventPlayer;
                    const isPlaying = player.getPlayerState() === 1;
                    if (hasIframe && isDifferentPlayer && isPlaying) {
                        player.pauseVideo();
                        console.log("pause");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
        let id = video.dataset.id;
        if (id.startsWith("PL")) {
            playerOptions.playerVars = playerOptions.playerVars || {};
            playerOptions.playerVars.listType = "playlist";
            playerOptions.playerVars.list = id;
        } else {
            playerOptions.videoId = id;
        }
        playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
        playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
        playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
        playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;
        players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
    }

    return {
        addPlayer,
        players
    };
}());
const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
    const playerVars = {
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1,
        disablekb: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3
        //playlist: 1
    };

    const defaults = {
        height: 360,
        host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
        playerVars,
        width: 640
    };

    function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
        const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
        Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
            if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
                combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
            }
        });
        return combined;
    }

    function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
        const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
        const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
        return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
    }

    function playerAdder(parent, playerOptions) {
        const wrapper = parent;
        return function () {
            initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
        };
    }

    function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
        createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    }

    return {
        adder: playerAdder
    };
}());

const loadPlayer = (function uiLoadPlayer() {
    function addPlayer(playerSelector, playerOptions) {
        const parent = document.querySelector(playerSelector).parentElement;
        const callback = managePlayer.adder(parent, playerOptions);
        callback();
    }

    return {
        add: addPlayer
    };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    // Initialize the first player
    loadPlayer.add(".playInitial", {
        playerVars: {
            loop: 1,
            playlist: "s24NT7TFkUw"
        }
    });
}
(function managePageA() {

    function handleModal(modalId) {
        const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
        modal.classList.remove("open");
    }


    function addTemplateToContainers() {
        const template = document.getElementById("image-templateA");
        const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
        const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");
        containers.forEach(function (container) {
            container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        });
    }

    function showExit(panelSelector, exitSelector) {
        const panel = document.querySelector(panelSelector);
        const closeButton = document.querySelector(exitSelector);
        panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
            closeButton.classList.add("visible");
        });
    }

    function resetPage() {
        handleModal("myModal");
        //addTemplateToContainers();
        showExit(".panel-container", ".exit");
    }

    function modalClickHandler() {
        // Destroy the first player if it exists
        if (videoPlayer.players[0]) {
            videoPlayer.players[0].destroy();
        }
        resetPage();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        // Initialize the rest of the players when the modal is clicked
        loadPlayer.add(".playa", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playb", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playc", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playd", {
            playerVars: {
                playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
            }
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playe", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });

        console.log("hit");
        // myModal.classList.remove("open");
    }
    const closeModal = document.querySelector(".exitInitial");
    closeModal.addEventListener("click", modalClickHandler);
}());


(function managePageB() {

    function handleModal(modalId) {
        const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
        modal.style.display = "none";
        modal.classList.add("open");
        modal.offsetWidth = modal.offsetWidth;
        modal.classList.remove("open");
    }


    function addTemplateToContainers() {
        const template = document.getElementById("image-templateB");
        const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".curtain-container");
        const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");

        containers.forEach(function (container) {
            container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        });
    }

    function hideContainer(containerSelector) {
        const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
        container.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function showCurtain(curtainSelector) {
        const curtain = document.querySelector(curtainSelector);
        curtain.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function showContainer(containerSelector) {
        const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
        container.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function resetPage() {
        handleModal("myModal");
        addTemplateToContainers();
        hideContainer(".containerA");
        showCurtain(".curtain-container");
        showContainer(".containerB");
    }

    function exitClickHandler() {
        videoPlayer.players.forEach(function (player) {
            player.destroy();
        });
        resetPage();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        // Initialize the rest of the players when exit is clicked
        loadPlayer.add(".playf", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playg", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playh", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playi", {
            playerVars: {
                playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
            }
        });
        loadPlayer.add(".playj", {
            videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
        });

        console.log("hit");

    }
    const exitButton = document.querySelector(".exit");
    exitButton.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);

}());
```

```css
svg {
  --color-a: #1155cc;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: #1155cc;
  --color-d: black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}

body:has(.modal.open) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 3;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: transparent;
}

.modal-content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;

  padding: 1px;
}

.modal-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.modal-content:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* just in case*/
}

:root {
  --wide: 8.8%;
  --angle1: 0;
  --angle2: -90;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 8s;
}

.panel.slide {
  transition-delay: 2s;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px 0;
}

.containerA {
}

.containerB {
}

.container {
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);*/
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.exitInitial {
  transform: translatey(100%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*margin: auto auto 0;*/
  top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*margin: 10px auto 0;*/
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exitInitial.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exitInitial::before,
.exitInitial::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitInitial::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.splash-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: none;
  opacity: 1; /* Fully visible */
  cursor: default;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.splash-screen.hide {
  opacity: 0; /* Fully transparent */
  transition-delay: 400ms;
  cursor: default;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 3s;
}

.panel-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-container .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.modal:not(.open) ~ .panel-container .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.curtain-left,
.curtain-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 3s;
}

.curtain-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.curtain-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-left::before,
.curtain-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
}

.curtain-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain-container.hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.curtain-container:not(.hide) > .curtain-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
  /*visibility: visible;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.curtain-container:not(.hide) > .curtain-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
  /*visibility: visible;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.container2 {
  max-width: 510px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 100vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.container2 div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container2 img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
}

.blog-pager {
  max-width: 674px;
  height: 52px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
      rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
      transparent 7.5px,
      transparent 10px
    );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.exit {
  position: relative;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exitB a {
  position: relative;
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.exitB a::before,
.exitB a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitB a::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid #1155cc;
  background: #121212;
  height: 108px;
}

.footer {
  margin: 0 -8px;
}

.wrap.hide {
  display: none;
}

.containerB.hide {
  display: none;
}

.containerA.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-screen">

   
 
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button class="exitInitial" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="wrap hide">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="playInitial remove"></div>
  
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end modal -->

<template id="image-templateA">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png" alt="Image 1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png" alt="Image 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png" alt="Image 5">
</template>

<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="slide panel-left">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide panel-right">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-container">


    <div class="containerA ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ratio-keeper ">
                <div class="video video-frame " data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="playa"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="playb"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="playc"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="playd"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="playe" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-pager ">
            <button class="exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>

        </div>

    </div>

  <template id="image-templateB">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lNH6CGY.png" alt="Image 1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8bPDWNh.png" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HgKNKxe.png" alt="Image 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nCRNnjS.png" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1SJgqB8.png" alt="Image 5">
</template>

<div class="curtain-container hide">
  <div class="slide curtain-left">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide curtain-right">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="containerB hide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playf"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playh"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playi"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playj" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-pager">
         <div class="exitB">
          <a href="#" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 

  <div class="footer ">
                    <div class="tyJCtd mGzaTb Depvyb baZpAe">
      <div class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke ">
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text1">text</span>
        </a>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <span class="text2">|</span>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text3">text</span>
        </a>
         <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <span class="text4">|</span>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text5">text</span><span class="text6">text</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div  class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke">
        <span class="jgG6ef text7">text</span>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div  class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke">
        <span class="text8">text</span>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
        const template = document.getElementById("image-templateA");
        const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
        const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");

        containers.forEach(function (container) {
            container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! The code in your fiddle is to basically have a play button over a designed element that triggers a play method on the video it's covering. What do you mean by "unhide" all the videos? That would defeat the purpose of the code provided.

Comment: So, then you would just be using the native YouTube play button to play the videos, but want the borders? Can you take a screen shot and edit your question to show what you are looking for?

Comment: The question is: Why do you need all this code then if you don't want to use its functionality? Do you want the borders? (there are easier ways) - or a playlist? Or what is it? Because right now it sounds like as if you come into a garage with a motorcycle, asking to get the engine removed and replaced with pedals, and we wonder why you didn't simply buy a bicycle in the first place.

Comment: Possibly css scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "slight shift" you experienced is simply caused by the scrollbar, so when the modal is opened, the scrollbar of `<body>` is hidden, and it will not be hidden until the modal is closed.

The easiest way to solve this is by removing the `overflow: hidden` from the `body:has(.modal.open)` selector:

```
body:has(.modal.open) {
  overflow: hidden; /* remove only this or along with the selector */
}
```

### EDIT

Since OP wants to keep the body's overflow hidden, we could make the scrollbar hidden instead and show it until the panel opening ended.

First we can add this CSS to prevent layout shift from happening when scrollbar is toggled on/off:

```
.outer-container {
  padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
}
```

Then we can add this CSS to hide the scrollbar:

```
.hide-scrollbar {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Then we can add the `hide-scrollbar` to `<html>` tag when the `exitInitial` is clicked:

```
function modalClickHandler() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.add('hide-scrollbar'); // add this
    // Destroy the first player if it exists
    ...
}
```

Then finally, we can remove the class to show the scrollbar again once the transition of the panel opening ends:

```
  const panelLeft = document.querySelector(".panel-left");
  panelLeft.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.remove('hide-scrollbar');
  });
```

Result:

```js
/*global YT */
/*jslint browser:true */
/*jslint devel: true */
window.onload = function() {
  const splashScreen = document.querySelector(".splash-screen");
  splashScreen.classList.add("hide");

  const panel = document.querySelector(".panel");
  panel.classList.add("slide");

  const wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
  splashScreen.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    splashScreen.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    wrap.classList.remove("hide");
  });

  const closeButton = document.querySelector(".exitInitial");
  panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    closeButton.classList.add("visible");
  });

  const panelLeft = document.querySelector(".panel-left");
  panelLeft.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.remove('hide-scrollbar');
  });
};


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    if (player === players[0]) {
      shufflePlaylist(player);
    }
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const eventPlayer = event.target;
    if (eventPlayer !== players[0]) {
      if (event.data === 1) {
        players.forEach(function pauseOtherVideos(player) {
          const hasIframe = player.getIframe();
          const isDifferentPlayer = player !== eventPlayer;
          const isPlaying = player.getPlayerState() === 1;
          if (hasIframe && isDifferentPlayer && isPlaying) {
            player.pauseVideo();
            console.log("pause");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    let id = video.dataset.id;
    if (id.startsWith("PL")) {
      playerOptions.playerVars = playerOptions.playerVars || {};
      playerOptions.playerVars.listType = "playlist";
      playerOptions.playerVars.list = id;
    } else {
      playerOptions.videoId = id;
    }
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;
    players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
  }

  return {
    addPlayer,
    players
  };
}());
const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
    //playlist: 1
  };

  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function playerAdder(parent, playerOptions) {
    const wrapper = parent;
    return function() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder
  };
}());

const loadPlayer = (function uiLoadPlayer() {
  function addPlayer(playerSelector, playerOptions) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(playerSelector).parentElement;
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(parent, playerOptions);
    callback();
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  // Initialize the first player
  loadPlayer.add(".playInitial", {
    playerVars: {
      loop: 1,
      playlist: "s24NT7TFkUw"
    }
  });
}
(function managePageA() {

  function handleModal(modalId) {
    const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.classList.remove("open");
  }


  function addTemplateToContainers() {
    const template = document.getElementById("image-templateA");
    const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
    const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");
    containers.forEach(function(container) {
      container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    });
  }

  function showExit(panelSelector, exitSelector) {
    const panel = document.querySelector(panelSelector);
    const closeButton = document.querySelector(exitSelector);
    panel.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
      closeButton.classList.add("visible");
    });
  }

  function resetPage() {
    handleModal("myModal");
    //addTemplateToContainers();
    showExit(".panel-container", ".exit");
  }

  function modalClickHandler() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].classList.add('hide-scrollbar');
    // Destroy the first player if it exists
    if (videoPlayer.players[0]) {
      videoPlayer.players[0].destroy();
    }
    resetPage();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    // Initialize the rest of the players when the modal is clicked
    loadPlayer.add(".playa", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playb", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playc", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playd", {
      playerVars: {
        playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
      }
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playe", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });

    console.log("hit");
    // myModal.classList.remove("open");
  }
  const closeModal = document.querySelector(".exitInitial");
  closeModal.addEventListener("click", modalClickHandler);
}());


(function managePageB() {

  function handleModal(modalId) {
    const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modal.classList.add("open");
    modal.offsetWidth = modal.offsetWidth;
    modal.classList.remove("open");
  }


  function addTemplateToContainers() {
    const template = document.getElementById("image-templateB");
    const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".curtain-container");
    const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");

    containers.forEach(function(container) {
      container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    });
  }

  function hideContainer(containerSelector) {
    const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
    container.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function showCurtain(curtainSelector) {
    const curtain = document.querySelector(curtainSelector);
    curtain.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function showContainer(containerSelector) {
    const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
    container.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function resetPage() {
    handleModal("myModal");
    addTemplateToContainers();
    hideContainer(".containerA");
    showCurtain(".curtain-container");
    showContainer(".containerB");
  }

  function exitClickHandler() {
    videoPlayer.players.forEach(function(player) {
      player.destroy();
    });
    resetPage();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    // Initialize the rest of the players when exit is clicked
    loadPlayer.add(".playf", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playg", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playh", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playi", {
      playerVars: {
        playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
      }
    });
    loadPlayer.add(".playj", {
      videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
    });

    console.log("hit");

  }
  const exitButton = document.querySelector(".exit");
  exitButton.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);

}());
```

```css
svg {
  --color-a: #1155cc;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: #1155cc;
  --color-d: black;
}

body:has(.modal.open) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 3;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: transparent;
}

.modal-content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
}

.modal-content::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.modal-content:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* just in case*/
}

:root {
  --wide: 8.8%;
  --angle1: 0;
  --angle2: -90;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: 8s;
}

.panel.slide {
  transition-delay: 2s;
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px 0;
}

.containerA {}

.containerB {}

.container {
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: 15px auto 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);*/
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.exitInitial {
  transform: translatey(100%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /*margin: auto auto 0;*/
  top: auto;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*margin: 10px auto 0;*/
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exitInitial.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exitInitial::before,
.exitInitial::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitInitial::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.splash-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  background: none;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Fully visible */
  cursor: default;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
}

.splash-screen.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  /* Fully transparent */
  transition-delay: 400ms;
  cursor: default;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 3s;
}

.panel-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.modal:not(.open)~.panel-container .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

.modal:not(.open)~.panel-container .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
}

.curtain-left,
.curtain-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 3s;
}

.curtain-left.slide {
  left: 0;
}

.curtain-right.slide {
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-left::before,
.curtain-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
}

.curtain-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain-container.hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.curtain-container:not(.hide)>.curtain-left {
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 1px));
  /*visibility: visible;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.curtain-container:not(.hide)>.curtain-right {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 1px));
  /*visibility: visible;*/
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.container2 {
  max-width: 510px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 100vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.container2 div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container2 img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: auto;
}

.blog-pager {
  max-width: 674px;
  height: 52px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px, rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px, transparent 7.5px, transparent 10px);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.exit {
  position: relative;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exitB a {
  position: relative;
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.exitB a::before,
.exitB a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exitB a::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid #1155cc;
  background: #121212;
  height: 108px;
}

.footer {
  margin: 0 -8px;
}

.wrap.hide {
  display: none;
}

.containerB.hide {
  display: none;
}

.containerA.hide {
  display: none;
}

.outer-container {
  padding-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
}

.hide-scrollbar {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="splash-screen">



</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button class="exitInitial" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap hide">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="playInitial remove"></div>

  </div>

</div>
<!-- end modal -->

<template id="image-templateA">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png" alt="Image 1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png" alt="Image 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png" alt="Image 5">
</template>

<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="slide panel-left">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide panel-right">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="container2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-container">


  <div class="containerA ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper ">
        <div class="video video-frame " data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playa"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playb"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playc"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playd"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playe" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-pager ">
      <button class="exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <template id="image-templateB">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lNH6CGY.png" alt="Image 1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8bPDWNh.png" alt="Image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HgKNKxe.png" alt="Image 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nCRNnjS.png" alt="Image 4">
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1SJgqB8.png" alt="Image 5">
</template>

  <div class="curtain-container hide">
    <div class="slide curtain-left">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="container2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide curtain-right">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="container2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="containerB hide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playf"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playh"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playi"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="playj" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-pager">
      <div class="exitB">
        <a href="#" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="footer ">
    <div class="tyJCtd mGzaTb Depvyb baZpAe">
      <div class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke ">
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text1">text</span>
        </a>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <span class="text2">|</span>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text3">text</span>
        </a>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <span class="text4">|</span>
        <span class="C9DxTc"> </span>
        <a class="XqQF9c" href="#" target="_blank">
          <span class="text5">text</span><span class="text6">text</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke">
        <span class="jgG6ef text7">text</span>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="zfr3Q  CDt4Ke">
        <span class="text8">text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const template = document.getElementById("image-templateA");
  const curtainContainer = document.querySelector(".panel-container");
  const containers = curtainContainer.querySelectorAll(".container2");

  containers.forEach(function(container) {
    container.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  });
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/h9betxm8/)

Comment: A more difficult way to solve this would be doing what?

Comment: @EveNinnall need to find a way... but more importantly, do you want to keep the body scroll hidden when the modal is opened?

Comment: Yes it should be hidden.

Comment: @EveNinnall in that case, what if we also keep it hidden until the curtain is fully opened while also keeping it scrollable when it's opening?

Comment: Yes, that would be good.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with it?

Comment: The lateral shift is still there in the code: https://jsfiddle.net/4fx7szn6/1/

Comment: @EveNinnall here https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/h9betxm8/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257019/discussion-between-eve-ninnall-and-damzaky).

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out how to do now. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/replacing-modal-with-4-modal-buttons-that-open-up-to-4-videos/441077/2?u=asasass I am confused on how to do it.

Comment: @EveNinnall if that's your own question, can you make another stackoverflow question perhaps?

Comment: I prefer sitepoint because it's more community based where other people can share their input and insight. I learn a lot from asking on there. Maybe you can join it?

Comment: I learned how to code basically from asking questions on sitepoint, it's very good for learning.

Comment: i'll think about it

Comment: That is where I got started building all these video code creations I have been coming up with. Learning from asking questions on there. It's more discussion based where you learn.

Comment: Currently I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/3x6nqa1t/

3 buttons on the page that when clicked on should open up to videos.

I wrote the javascript for it but haven't been able to figure it out.

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/replacing-modal-with-4-modal-buttons-that-open-up-to-4-videos/441077/9

Comment: Maybe I should be using data-target="" instead of data-destination="", as that is used in the example that is given: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74403540/trying-to-implement-pop-up-video-modal-code

Comment: I don't understand how the code would be written. Similar to how my other functions are written.

Comment: Currently, all the buttons are clickable, if I only want, .buttonA to be clickable, how do I do that here? https://jsfiddle.net/c63w0fdy/

forEach and All can be removed then.

Each button needs to have its own javascript.

Comment: Looking in here, I have made progress, but still need help figuring it out: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/replacing-modal-with-4-modal-buttons-that-open-up-to-4-videos/441077/26

Comment: I have lots of different questions and it's easier to ask them on sitepoint than it is on here because sitepoint is more discussion based.